# Reinstalling Django App - Data tables not re-created

Tags: python, django

I am trying to reinstall one of my apps on my project site. These are the steps that I have followed to do so:

1. Removing the name of the installed app from `settings.py`
2. Manually deleting the app folder from the project folder
3. Manually removing the data tables from PostgreSQL
4. Copying the app folder back into the project folder; making sure that all files, except `__init__.py` is removed.
5. Run `python manage.py sqlmigrate app_name 0001`
6. Run `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`
7. Run `python manage.py migrate app_name`
8. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
9. Run `python manage.py migrate`

However, after all these steps the message I am getting is that there are "no changes detected" and the data tables have not been recreated in the database, PostgreSQL.

Am I missing some additional steps?

Comment: If you are doing everything manually then you have to remove app entries from django_migration table.

Comment: How do you do that? My Django version is 1.8

Comment: I think you can do `python manage.py migrate --fake [appname] 0000`

Comment: This maybe an off topic comment but I would prefer to use tools like `alembic` for handling migrations, as this allows downgrade and upgrade versioning too, which i suppose, isn't there in django migrations

Comment: It's work for me! thx

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have managed to solve the problem. The command, `python manage.py sqlmigrate app_name 0001`, produces the SQL statements required for the table creation. Thus, I copied and paste the output into the PostgreSQL console and got the tables created. It seems to work for now, but I am not sure if there will be repercussions later.